# I'm trying to create function to fetch data

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, fetch

I'm trying to create function to fetch data with multiple arguments but i dont know how to get them in combination.Its fetching first argument then second and so on not combined

```
function GetProductByIng(...$ingridients) {
    global $db;
    $ings = implode(',',$ingridients);
    $querys = $db->query("SELECT DISTINCT p.prod_id, p.prod_name, ig.name 
                          FROM products p 
                            LEFT JOIN product_ingridients pi ON ( p.prod_id = pi.prod_id) 
                            LEFT JOIN ingridients ig ON (pi.ing_id = ig.id) 
                          WHERE pi.ing_id IN ($ings)");

    $result = $querys->fetch_all();

    return $result;
}
```

if anyone can help me to edit it and get combination

**product_ingredients**

```
id |   prod_id   | ing_id
---+-------------+--------
1  |      1      | 1 
2  |      2      | 5 
3  |      1      | 5 
4  |      2      | 1 
5  |      3      | 1 
6  |      3      | 7
```

Comment: please show an example of what it is doing, and also what you would like it to do

Comment: Its getting all products that got ingredients from table product_ingredients
But its getting them by every ingredient not combined

Comment: A sample of the database would be useful then

Comment: I edited the first post

Comment: The Example will be GetProductByIng(1,5) and it will fetch only prod_id 1 and 2 because 3 don't have both the ingredients